# Python Error: No module named mrjob.job

Tags: python, python-import, mrjob

I am running the following simple script from the [book](http://feederio.com/files/book/1477082936747_02862b1b55053c217148432eb64c2ba9.pdf) and getting the following error

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordCount(MRJob):
 def mapper(self, _, line):
  for word in line.split():
   yield(word, 1)
 def reducer(self, word, counts):
  yield(word, sum(counts))

if __name__ == '__main__':
 MRWordCount.run()
```

Using cygwin64 on windows 10 it returns the following error:

```
User001@Ubuntu /cygdrive/c/Users/User001/PycharmProjects/TestProject
$ python preparation.py input.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preparation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mrjob.job import MRJob
ImportError: No module named mrjob.job
```

Here is what I did:

1. I installed mrjob using `pip install mrjob` and it installed successfully.
2. I have checked that files exist in site-packages/mrjob and job.py file also exist and I can open the file and see the methods inside that file.
3. I am using Pycharm so when I try to import mrjob it also gives me syntax completion that is pycharm recognizes where is the file.

Now I do not understand why it is unable to get this module. Can anybody help ? Thanks

Comment: Check if you have multiple python versions installed

Comment: Check if you have a local `mrjob.py` file or `mrjob` directory with an `__init__.py` file, masking the package.

Comment: I recently installed windows so there is no other python version. I have the `__init__.py` and `mrjob.py` files too in the packages

Comment: I figured it out. @Robin was right I had two versions of python (2.7). Though i didn't install it myself. I just installed cygwin64 and it was installed from there. So whenever I run python from cygwin it runs python 2.7 but when I run it from command prompt it runs correctly with python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

> When a module named **spam** is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named **spam.py** in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - **PYTHONPATH** (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.

Which means you should avoid naming your modules with the same name as standard-library or **built-in** module names. So you'd better rename your package name or script file name instead of `mrjob.py`.